# PHP and MySQL INSERT INTO does not work -- No error and no new lines in DB

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, mysqli, insert-into

This my first post on this site.  I will do my best to include all the needed information.  I have read many of the answers regarding this same problem. I have tried many combinations and none of them work. The following is the one that gets me the closest to my very simple goal --> Write a line to my database.  This code is in a password protected portion of my site.

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include("../ConfigFiles/ConnectDB_live.php");

echo "<br> I am still alive? <br>";

//Can I read from DB --- This worked on live
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM invoicelist_table";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $row['FileName'] . "<br>";
}

//Can I write to the DB --- Live

//Lets mix a few ideas together
    mysql_query($bdd,"INSERT INTO `invoicelist_table` (`InvoiceNo`, `FileName`, `FilePath`) VALUES ('9999', 'MyName', 'MyPath')") ;
    echo mysql_error();
    //or die(mysql_error());

echo "I wrote something to the DB successfully <br>";

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
echo "The connection to DB is closed";
?>
```

Note that I can read the database just fine but I can't seem to write to it.  I have also tried the recommended mysqli version but that does not work either.  I have tried various ways of trapping an error and I get nothing... literally nothing!  I have tried at least a dozen syntax variations.  I am ready to throw up!

I am new to web programming and find most of my answers online.  I think I am doing pretty good for my limited knowledge.  This one is blowing my mind.  None of the recommendations I read about work or make sense to me.  So please answer me like I am a 5-yr old!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Give the below answer a try. Another thing I might look at is the datatype of your "InvoiceNo" column. You're trying to pass in a character type, but you're using what tends to be a numeric type.

Comment: The field is a string because I used to have letters in there sometimes.  I may change it in the future.  I use mostly numbers now.

Comment: Since your invoice numbers are probably going to be unique, I highly recommend making that column a number of some sort (not anything with a decimal like float) and auto increment as a property. Then, set it as a primary key and index it, in the future of course, but better sooner than later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your connection as the second parameter or remove it if you didnt close the connection

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoicelist_table` (`InvoiceNo`, `FileName`, `FilePath`) VALUES ('9999', 'MyName', 'MyPath')") ;
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/mysql_query)

Comment: Agreed, even though if it's the only open connection that's unnecessary. Upvote!

Comment: So all I had to do was get rid of the connection reference.  I knew I was close.  I will surely be back with more questions further on.  THANK YOU !!!